# Firebug console interactive vs echo behavior

Tags: firebug

The console in Firebug just echoes everything I enter, rather than interpret it as before.  If there is an option to toggle this behavior, I cannot find it.

```
Command line window:
var x=5;
x*x;

Console:
>>> var x=5; x*x;
```

How is the interactive mode restored?

Comment: Solved:  apparently reinstalling Firebug corrected the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall of Firebug restored the broken functionality to working status.